# How to select parent checkbox when i select one of child checkboxed in jQuery (Fancytree)

Tags: jquery, laravel, fancytree

I want to select parent option (checkbox option) when I select child option like one of the child option in jQuery. I am using the fancytree package.

Here is my code :

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
        checkbox: true,
        selectMode: 2,
        icon: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        clickFolderMode: 4,
        source: @json($streams),

        init: function(event, node) {
        },

        select: function(event, data) {
            // console.log(data.node.parent);
            // if(data.node.parent){
            //     data.node.parent.setSelected(true);
            // }
            // console.log(data.node);

            var selNodes = data.tree.getSelectedNodes();
            var selKeys = $.map(selNodes, function(node){
                return node.data.id;
            });

            $("#streams_values").val(selKeys);
        }
    });
```